# Serverless framework - uploading binary files to S3 become corrupted

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, serverless, busboy

I have an endpoint that takes in form data including a file. This file can be a text file, image, or pdf. I'm using busboy (v0.2.14) to parse the form data. That code looks like this:

```
        let buffers = [];

        file.on('data', data => buffers.push(data));

        file.on('end', () => {
            result.filename = filename;
            result.contentType = mimetype;

            // Concat the chunks into a Buffer
            result.file = new Buffer.concat(buffers);
        });
        // ...
        busboy.write(event.body, event.isBase64Encoded ? 'base64' : 'binary');
        busboy.end();
```

However, when I push the file data up to S3 using the AWS SDK (v2.97.0), all the binary files are corrupted when I go to view them. This does not happen to text files. The S3 upload code looks like this:

```
static myPutObject(bucketName, fileName, data, contentType, acl) {
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: fileName,
        Body: data,
        ACL: acl,
        ContentType: contentType,
        ContentEncoding: 'base64'
    };

    return new AWS.S3().putObject(params).promise();
}
```

I've tried everything that I can find on Stack Overflow or GitHub with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 is an "object in" and "object out" store. It does not know whether your content is binary or text or utf-16 encoding. It stores all the bytes as it receives and serves them when requested.

Here is how we validated whether the problem is on S3 or with our code.

1. Write the binary file locally
2. Send the same file to S3
3. Download from S3
4. Verify local file hash and download file hash for file integrity
5. That will help you to verify binary file contents.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using API gateway in the front. apiGateway will mangle the incoming binary unless you specifically enabled binary Media Types.
If you’re using SLS to deploy, then you can just add:

```
apiGateway:
  binaryMediaTypes:
  - '*/*'
```

in the provider section

Read here: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#binary-media-types